How to pass environment variables to app running in production mode?
I'm trying to run my app in production mode locally, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass env variables.
I'm using dotenv-cli and I've tried running,
dotenv -e .env.production.local -- npx expo start --no-dev --minify

However this does nothing, as the variables are undefined.
There's absolutely nothing in the docs regarding this particular scenario.
Is there any way to do this? I need to debug a crash, which happens only in production mode; do I have to rebuild my app every single time (or use EAS update) after every change?

You can refer to the docs below to use the environment specific settings.
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/
To highlight the specific section on how it works:
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/#how-variables-are-loaded

We can pass environment variables through the application start script
cmd/> APP_NAME="My App Name" start-app-script


I have about 50 env variables, which is why I was using dotenv-cli. Is there a better way than writing each one out?

What is your coding stack? Node, C#, C++?

Create a shell script file and write all environment variables there. Then run the script.
